# Run chrome apps/other apps as a background service

Tags: google-chrome, background

I have a Chrome app (a website) that I want to run in the background in Windows 10. That means that it won't be minimized but as a background service/in the task bar. How can I achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

have you considered [chrome-headless](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome)?

```
chrome \
  --headless \                   # Runs Chrome in headless mode.
  --disable-gpu \                # Temporarily needed if running on Windows.
  --remote-debugging-port=9222 \
  https://www.chromestatus.com   # URL to open. Defaults to about:blank.
```